# Windows python setup.py install does not distribute module python files

Tags: python, module, packaging, setup.py

Ive searched the web for hours but I am not able to find out what im doing wrong. 
I install my own package through `python setup.py install`. This works, although im not able to `import mymodule` anywhere on the system.

This is how the directory looks like:

```
C:\PyDev\simple_test\mymodule
C:\PyDev\simple_test\setup.py
C:\PyDev\simple_test\mymodule\__init__.py
```

With: __init__.py

```
def sayhello():
    print("Hello")
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='mymodule'
)
```

commandline:
`python setup.py install`

It does that without raising any error. But when I look at the installed .egg file in the site-packages, it only contains an EGG-INFO directory, and no source files whatsoever...

This is the output of the install command:

```
(venv) C:\PyDev\simple_test>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating mymodule.egg-info
writing mymodule.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to mymodule.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to mymodule.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'mymodule.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'mymodule.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'mymodule.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build\lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

creating build
creating build\bdist.win-amd64
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying mymodule.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying mymodule.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying mymodule.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying mymodule.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist\mymodule-0.0.0-py3.7.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing mymodule-0.0.0-py3.7.egg
Copying mymodule-0.0.0-py3.7.egg to c:\pydev\simple_test\venv\lib\site-packages
Adding mymodule 0.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\pydev\simple_test\venv\lib\site-packages\mymodule-0.0.0-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for mymodule==0.0.0
Finished processing dependencies for mymodule==0.0.0
```

If I run `python setup.py develop` it does seem to work. Then I can access the package throughout my whole system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what the cause is but two things stand out:

- You don't have `packages` specified in your setup.py
- The name of your module directory is different from the name of your main directory

I could imagine that the combination of these two factors result in `setuptools` not being able to find your source.

You could try renaming your src directory or changing your `setup.py` to

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='mymodule',
      packages=find_packages()
)
```

Comment: packages=find_packages() did the trick! Thanks! 
I thought setup.py automatically searched for .py and \__init__.py files to determine what packages are?